# Appointment.Invitees is always empty in UWP AppointmentManager

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, capability

An appointment that has participants, always return an empty collection when queried for using the appointment.Invitees property.

Here is what I am trying to do,

```
var calendarStore = await AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType.AllCalendarsReadOnly);
var appointments = await calendarStore.FindAppointmentsAsync(DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeSpan.FromDays(30), new FindAppointmentsOptions() { IncludeHidden = true });
foreach (var appointment in appointments)
{
    // appointment.Invitees is always null, even for appointments that has some! 
    foreach (var invitee in appointment.Invitees)
    {
        // do something here...
    }
}
```

I tried to add Contacts capability in addition to Appointment, but in vain. 
Any thoughts on why such a bizarre behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The [`appointmentsSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) capability is necessary when access the [`Invitees`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appointments.appointment) property.

```
 <Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
         xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
         xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
         xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
     IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="appointments" />
    <uap:Capability Name="contacts" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="appointmentsSystem" />   
 </Capabilities>
```

> No one may request access to this capability for store submission

Please note that the [`appointmentsSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) is useless in store app.

Comment: I tried to add this restricted capability to the manifest file manually, but I see do difference. This is what I have now. 

 <Capabilities>

    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap:Capability Name="userAccountInformation" />
    <uap:Capability Name="appointments" />
    <uap:Capability Name="contacts" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="appointmentsSystem" />
  </Capabilities>